# Multiplicacion en sql , error por INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo este Query

```
SELECT
    SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo),
    SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion),
    SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''),
    SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,''),
    SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0),
    SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0),
    SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0),
    SI_Dif_Dinero = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0) 
    FROM
    SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
    FULL JOIN SI_Conteo c
    ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo
    AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion
    FULL JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
    ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
    WHERE c.SI_Num_Articulo = 200116 OR t.SI_Articulo = 200116
```

el cual me trae el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema esta en que por ejemplo las ubicaciones `DD5131` y `EE2102` no existen en la tabla `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t` por lo tanto cuando hago la siguiente operación

`SI_Dif_Dinero = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)`

no me lo multiplica por el valor que trae `m.SI_Costo_Promedio` ya que me trae un valor NULL

entonces como puedo decirle de que si la ubicacion  es nueva igual lo multiplique por el `m.SI_Costo_Promedio`

Comment: Como puede traerte null, si estas usando COALESCE justamente para evitar que traiga null?

Comment: Por eso le pongo 0

Comment: no sera.. que en lugar de hacer esto SI_Dif_Dinero = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0), queres hacer esto? SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0) (primero restar, despues multiplicar?)

Comment: No da. es que como esas dos ubicaciones que mencionono no estan en la tabla `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t` al hacer esta comparacion  `AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion` el entiende que esas ubicaciones no existen.

Comment: y si no estan las ubicaciones que esperas que pase?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función IsNull() de la siguiente forma:

```
IsNull(columna1 * columna2, 0);
```

Esto indica que, si la multiplicación de ambas columnas resulta en un **Null** el resultado es 0.

Espero te ayude mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: `ISNULL` no es un comando, es una función.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando la comparación del ultimo `JOIN` de la siguiente forma

```
ON  COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo) = m.SI_Num_Articulo
```